# can someone explain this Python input/output code

Tags: python-3.x, variables, input, output

The code in this practice course I am taking works as intended. But I do not understand why it works the way it does. I am sort of new so some of my terminology may be off. Code for reference:

```
print("Hi!")
name = input("What's your name? ")

print("It's nice to meet you,", name)
answer = input("Are you enjoying the course? ")

if answer == "Yes":
    print("That's good to hear!")
else:
    print("Oh no! That makes me sad!")
```

I have 2 questions:

1. When I am declaring the variable `name` it uses an
   `input`function, but how does the code get read so it knows what I
   have typed as an input? I do not see where it fits in the code here, before or after the quotes maybe?
2. the variable `answer` isn't ever specifically written to be printed out. Meaning i don't see a `print` command for it except for the previous line.It appears to be to just be defined with the `input` function. Is the `print` command working for all lines below it as well?

Answer (score 0):

This might give you a better understanding: https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_input.asp

The input function basically takes the string passed to the function, prints it, and reads the string that the user types. The user can finish the string by hitting ENTER or RETURN. Essentially, the input function just reads whatever the user has typed up to the newline character `\n`

So if I have `answer = input('Please answer this question: ')` then firstly the program will print out `"Please answer this question: "` and then the user can type whatever, and when they hit enter, that string that was typed is saved in `answer`

Answer (score 0):

1. `input` is a blocking function. Meaning it waits for something to happen before returning the value. In this case, it's waiting for the user to enter their name on the screen.
2. Not sure I understand your question. The variable `answer` is actually never printed out. Again you are waiting for the user's `input` (this time, expecting either a Yes or No), and then you are checking it in the `if` statement. If it was "Yes", you print "That's good to hear", `else` you print "Oh no! That makes me sad!". But the `answer` variable (eg. "Yes"), is never actually printed to the screen.

It might make a little more sense if you read the code from right to left (eg. take what comes back from `input`, and put it in `name`)